# Changing layer's ArcSDE data source user name?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog

I am a new hire and I'm in the process up setting up my database connections and default instance. I set up my personal database connection to the server under my name.

I received a MXD from a coworker and saved it on my computer. In the layer properties source tab, the data source shows that the **user name** is still under my coworkers name.

**I would like to change the user name to my name in the source data.**

Is there anyway to change the user name for this, and perhaps all of the layers at once?

[image: I want to reset the user name here]

Comment: It's ***not possible*** to change the owner of a table registered with the geodatabase.  The supported mechanism is to GRANT SELECT access to the table as the other user to the desired owner, copy the table contents as that owner, then DROP the original table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-point your layers to another connection using *Set Data Sources* in ArcCatalog

[image]

In the dialog that opens, select all the layers you need to update, and choose *Replace All*

[image]

In the Replace All dialog, in the second field add the path to your new connection (as per your comment *I set up my personal database connection to the server under my name*)

[image]

When you OK it will update the New Data Source for all the layers, and another OK will create a new MXD pointing at your database connection, and therefore using your connection username properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: User Name Change Solution]

In ArcCatalog, right click the MXD and Set data source. See # 1 below in the photo. Only changing the user name here did not work. # 2 below in the photo I changed the entire file path. This obviously worked.